# How do I find the total of a category after filtering and needing to use at least one more criteria?

Tags: excel, filter, sumifs, subtotal, sumproduct

So I have an excel file where the data shows sales made, paths taken to get to the sale, test and control indicator, CPM clicks, and impressions accordingly with a path.

All categories go from 2 to 12697

Column B has the paths. You can see how that looks in the screenshot.

Column C is # of orders made. Column D is order total for the sale made. Column F indicates whether a sale is a test or control.

I used the filter function to get the total revenues sales whose paths ended in "h" but I am struggling to find total revenue sales that has a "T".

Function used to find total revenue sales whose paths ended with h, after I used the filter function. I filtered "ends with h" already.

`SUBTOTAL(109,D:D)`

Basically, what I want to do is find the total test revenue for sales whose paths ended in "E1w" and is a test revenue, indicated by the letter "T" after filtering data where a path ends with "E1w".

Any help is highly appreciated.

Here is how the excel spreadsheet looks like

[image: [example](https://imgur.com/a/vkRFXq3) https://imgur.com/a/vkRFXq3]

Comment: instead of using words to describe your data, post a data sample. Even a screenshot is better than words. Then describe the desired result and the logic that leads to it. Please edit your question to do that. Don't post that in a comment. When you have updated your question, you can post a comment to alert people who are following your question.

Comment: I uploaded a sample.

Comment: I don't see how the visible path ends in `h` in your screenshot. Subtotal will total all the visible rows, so if you can filter the table to meet the requirements, using column F for T, then what is the problem??

Comment: Yep, I forgot I can further filter my table. Thank you for noticing that and letting me know.